# How do I get list from imported python file

Tags: python, import

This was my python file, and I want to move “names” list to other file, and import it.

```
name = [“one”,
        “two”,
        “three”]
for doing_job in name:
        (doing something)
```

I have imported sucsessfully, but I can’t get that “name” list the main python file.
made like this

main.py

```
from settings import name
for doing_job in name
```

settings/name.py

```
name = [“one”,
        “two”,
        “three”]
return name
```

How can I fix this and get “name” on the main.py file?
Error now is

```
for doing_job in name:  
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in python code. Fix them to straight quotes.

Comment: That didn’t fix it. :/

Comment: I didn't say it would. I assumed it was a copying error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name variable by calling `name.name`. Check the example below:

Main.py file:

```
from settings import name

for n in name.name:
    print(n)
```

settings/name.py file:

```
name = [["one","two","three"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok unless the curly quotes use straight ones, also it seeems you are missing a ending bracket and why a "useless" return outside function?

```
name = [['one',
        'two',
        'three']]
```

You can use double `""` too

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
from settings import name
for doing_job in name.name:
    print(doing_job)
```

or

```
from settings.name import name
for doing_job in name:
    print(doing_job)
```